# Windows 10 , Spark error (bin/bin) não encontra arquivo winutils.exe

Tags: hadoop

Instalei o Spark e o Hadoop no Windows 10, e estou com um erro no caminho do arquivo `winutils.exe`. Já coloquei na pasta adequada, já defini a variável de ambiente `HADOOP_HOME` como  `C:\hadoop\bin`, porém no erro aparece:

> ERROR Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
>   java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable C:\hadoop\bin\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.

Aparecem estes dois "bin" quando deveria ser um. Estranho.

No diretório `spark/bin` tanto faz digitar `spark-shell` ou `pyspark`, mostra o mesmo erro.

Fiz uns testes com o hadoop e está ok. Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Obrigado ao Denis, era isso mesmo, estava procurando aonde ele determinava a variável , esta foi a melhor solução. Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defina `HADOOP_HOME` apenas como `C:\hadoop`, no erro aparece a pasta `bin` duas vezes